# Concatenate 10000 dataframes from loop in groups of 100 to one big dataframe and save to csv/txt-file

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I'm working with building stocks and so big dataframes. I'm doing input parameter sampling for 10000 stocks of 1000 buildings (so if every building is 1 line in a csv-file, it's about 10000000 lines to write to csv-files).
In order to execute this (without getting MemoryError in Python) and prepare files for the simulation program, I will need to group those stocks together into smaller parts (instead of one big file), for example 100 stocks of 1000 at a time. Any idea how to do this?

I prepared a small example in which I have an original dataframe in which I overwrite a column within a loop.
In the end, I stack all dataframes (generated in the loop) into one big dataframe (which contains then x times the original dataframe with changes here and there. Instead of stacking everything into one big df and saving that to csv, I want to stack them by 100 stocks at a time.

Now I'm stacking all stocks in a big df and splitting it afterwards into pieces with an extra 'ID'-column. Is there a way to do this in the process (imagine I need need 1000 or 100000 stocks in total)? Calculating and stacking 100 stocks -> save them to csv -> calculate and stack the next 100 stocks -> save them to csv ...

**Tried code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_or = pd.DataFrame({"Case": [1,2,3,4,5,6],  
                         "A": [3,5,2,8,4,1],       
                         "B": [10,12,24,8,57,84]})

print(df_or)

total = []

for i in range(0,1000):
    df = df_or.copy()
    df.loc[:, 'A'] = df_or.loc[:, 'A'].mul(i)   
    df.loc[:, 'ID'] = df.loc[:,'Case'] + i*100000
    print(df)

    total.append(df)

total = pd.concat(total)
total = total.sort_values('ID')

for i in range(0, 10): 
    stocks = total[((i) * 100 * 100000 <= total['ID']) & (total['ID'] <= (i + 1) * 100 * 100000)] 
    stocks.to_csv('stack100_' + str(i) + '.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have less than about a thousand files to write, you can have them open all at the same time; as you get the data, write each line to the appropriate file.

You'll need to keep the open files in a dictionary or similar, so you can write each line to the correct file and so you can close them all at the end.

Something like:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
import pandas as pd

df_or = pd.DataFrame({"Case": [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                         "A": [3,5,2,8,4,1],
                         "B": [10,12,24,8,57,84]})

with ExitStack() as stack:

    files = [
        stack.enter_context(open('stack100_' + str(j) + '.csv', 'w'))
        for j in range(0, 10)
    ]

    for i in range(0,1000):
        df = df_or.copy()
        df.loc[:, 'A'] = df_or.loc[:, 'A'].mul(i)
        df.loc[:, 'ID'] = df.loc[:,'Case'] + i*100000

        for j in range(0, 10):
            stocks = df[(
                (j) * 100 * 100000
                <= total['ID']) & (total['ID']
                <= (j + 1) * 100 * 100000
            )]
            stocks.to_csv(files[j], sep=',', index=False)

        del stocks, df
```

Comment: Is that true? I guess it depends on the size of the data you'll have to write to files in total?
Yeah well at 20.000.000 lines of writing, I got a MemoryError yesterday (I tried it to one file then) so I guess splitting up and saving in batches is the way to go (also for future bigger writing tasks).

Comment: Working line-by-line means you'll only have a couple of lines in memory at any time, so you won't have a problem running out. As soon as you read a line in (or a small batch), write it out again to free up space.

Comment: I've added an example how you might translate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a file in append mode, and write your file to it.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abalone.csv")

with open("output.csv", 'a') as outf:
    df.to_csv(outf)
```

In this way, you can read each file one at a time, aggregate and save to a file. Only one file is in memory at a time.

If you will only be analysing the files in batches later, I recommend thinking about saving to those batches *at this step* and then your files are more manageable.

Comment: Interesting comment. I'll have to try it out and see how it performs.

Comment: You can also switch writing headers off, which you'll want to do for everything except the first file save.